# Java dice game not correctly playing subsequent rounds of the game: boolean variable issue?

Tags: java

I've been working on a dice game and finally got it to work (by that, I mean I got the .class file to generate). However, there is something wrong with the logic of the game that I can't figure out. I think the program is interpreting the rules of the game wrong.

Here are the rules: A player rolls four dice for one round. In this first round, 
if the sum of the dice rolls equals a 6, 12, 13, 17, 19, or 23 the player wins and the game ends. If the player rolls a 9, 11, 18, or 24 on this round, the player loses. If the player rolls any other number, the sum of the dice becomes the "goal number" and the game keeps rolling the dice. 
The player must continue to roll the dice again until they roll a 23 and lose, or roll the sum of the dice from the first round again, and then wins.

When I run the game, it keeps using the rules from the first round, although the rules change for the subsequent rounds.

For example, here's one of the outputs I've gotten from the console

> Your sum of the dice values: 15. You rolled a sum of 15, so the game will keep playing until you roll this sum again.*(and then the second round rolls)* Your sum of the dice values: 17. You win!

Clearly this isn't right, because in this case you can only win if you roll a 15 again. It's clearly still using the winning values from the first time, which I don't understand because I have the do-while loop for the second round under the conditions keepPlaying = true and justOneRound = false, but it's still not acknowledging that justOneRound is false for the subsequent rounds.

Here is the code, (I know this sounds confusing but hopefully it makes sense once you see this):

```
// Declare boolean variables to tell if the user keeps playing in subsequent rounds (to be used by multiple methods).
public static boolean justOneRound = false;
public static boolean keepPlaying = true;

// Declare variables for the goal number and the sum of the dice on the first round. 
public static int firstRoundDiceSum = 0;

// main method header
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        // Play the game for at least one round, and then again if the user doesn't win or lose.
            do 
            {
                // Roll the dice (redirect to the roll() method) and declare a variable to hold the sum of the values that have returned. 
                firstRoundDiceSum = roll();

                // Print the sum of the rolled dice. 
                System.out.println("Your sum of the dice values: ");
                System.out.println(firstRoundDiceSum);

                // Determine if the user won or not. 
                if (firstRoundDiceSum == 6 ||firstRoundDiceSum == 12 ||firstRoundDiceSum == 13 ||firstRoundDiceSum == 17 || firstRoundDiceSum == 19 ||firstRoundDiceSum == 23)
                {
                    justOneRound = true;
                    keepPlaying = false;
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else if (firstRoundDiceSum == 9 ||firstRoundDiceSum == 11 ||firstRoundDiceSum == 18 ||firstRoundDiceSum == 24)
                {
                    justOneRound = true;
                    keepPlaying = false;
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else 
                {
                    justOneRound = false;
                    keepPlaying = true;
                    System.out.println("You rolled a sum of: " + firstRoundDiceSum + ", so the game will keep playing until you roll this sum again.");
                }
            } while (justOneRound = true);

        // Play the game for subsequent rounds until the user gets the goal number or loses.
        do 
            {   
                // Roll the dice (redirect to the roll2() method) and declare a variable to hold the sum of the values that have returned. 
                int laterRoundsDiceSum = roll2();

                // Print the sum of the rolled dice. 
                System.out.println("Your sum of the dice values: ");
                System.out.println(laterRoundsDiceSum);

                // Determine if the user won or not. 
                if (laterRoundsDiceSum == firstRoundDiceSum)
                {
                    keepPlaying = false;
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else if (laterRoundsDiceSum == 23)
                {
                    keepPlaying = false;
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else 
                {
                    keepPlaying = true;
                    System.out.println("You didn't roll " + firstRoundDiceSum + ", so you have to keep rolling until you get it!");
                }
            } while ((justOneRound = false) && (keepPlaying = true));
    }

    // roll() method header that rolls the die for the first round (creates a dieRoll object and gets a random value for the die).
    public static int roll()
    {
        do 
        {
            // Create a random class object.
            Random dieRoll = new Random();

            // Declare a variable for the sum, and set it to zero before the dice roll.
            int firstRoundDiceSum = 0;

            // Use a for-loop to roll the dice four times (with counter variable timesRolled).

            for (int timesRolled = 1; timesRolled <= 5; timesRolled ++)
            {
                int dieValue = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
                firstRoundDiceSum = firstRoundDiceSum + dieValue;
            }
            return firstRoundDiceSum;
        } while (justOneRound = true);
    }

    // roll() method header that rolls the die for the subsequent round(s) (creates a dieRoll object and gets a random value for the die).
    public static int roll2()
    {
        do 
        {
            // Create a random class object.
            Random dieRoll = new Random();

            // Declare a variable for the sum, and set it to zero before the dice roll.
            int laterRoundsDiceSum = 0;

            // Use a for-loop to roll the dice four times (with counter variable timesRolled).

            for (int timesRolled = 1; timesRolled <= 5; timesRolled ++)
            {
                int dieValue = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
                laterRoundsDiceSum = laterRoundsDiceSum + dieValue;
            }
            return laterRoundsDiceSum;
        } while (justOneRound = true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `justOneRound = true` should be `justOneRound == true` (well actually you should just write `while(justOneRound)`, but whatever). You have the same problem in every while-loop. Single equals is assignment, double equals is comparison

Comment: It worth noting that any decent IDE will warn you about such a mistake. All I did was paste your code into IntelliJ and it immediately highlighted the potential error.

Comment: Instead of `justOneRound = true`, did you mean `justOneRound == true` (or simply `while(justOneRound)`)?

Comment: roll and roll2 are identical, why do you need both? Neither needs a do/while wrapper either

Comment: Thanks: it was the == sign. A rather silly mistake that I keep forgetting about, really!